# how to remove first char with to_char or another function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the follow function in a SQL query:

```
to_char(currval('admatencionc."TMReporte_ID_reporte_seq"'::regclass),'FM0000')
```

It takes the sequence and converted  to a char filled with 0, but recently the sequence reached the 10000 place. I am looking a way to supress the first number to have again the 0000 number.

I am looking the documentation of to_char but I don't find anything.

Comment: use `substr()` on the result

Comment: jajaja that was to obvious, how I did not realize. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you actually appear to want the last 4 digits, rather than to remove the first char, use `right`:

```
SELECT right(to_char(..., ...), 4);
```

IMO it's cleaner to mathematically get the right value, then convert it to a string, though.

```
SELECT to_char(currval('blah') % 10000, 'FM0000');
```